# Can ridge regression be used on categorical dependent variable?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to apply ridge regression to a telecom churning data where dependent variable, Churn is a categorical variable, there are only 3 continuous predictor variables out of 30, where Multicollinearity exists somewhat. Can I use ridge regression?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a multinominal ridge regression:

The short answer is Yes!

See here for further explanation:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/why-does-ridge-regression-work-well-in-the-presence-of-multicollinearity

And consider the advice by Peter Flom regarding excact collinearity.

See also here: [Multinomial ridge regression using glmnet gives results with probabilities above one and negative for different target classes, any idea why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844910/multinomial-ridge-regression-using-glmnet-gives-results-with-probabilities-above) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

As your task is to classify the customers as `Churn` or `Non-Churn`, so its a classification task and not a regression task.

Ridge regression is used for regression purpose only as it needs the dependent variable to be continuous.

So for your analysis Ridge regression **can't** be used.

Special characteristic of Ridge regression is it works fine in presence of multicollinearity but with a continuous dependent variable.

You may refer this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression